# WebDriver, всплывающая подсказка

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

При вводе в поле e-mail чего-то вроде "абв" - появляется всплывающая подсказка, которая исчезает при клике по ней. Как можно ее отловить? В ресурсах страницы ничего подходящего не нашел.

Собственно, вот форма
https://app.heroicnow.com/login/

Как в selenium webdriver указать ее появление в asset?

Comment: Очень похоже на работу скрипта js. Поковыряйте их, может найдете каким образом он отображает. Вообще, как будто атрибут title появляется в этом поле, но по факту - нет. Если есть доступ к разработчикам, то лучше им и задать этот вопрос

Comment: У меня ничего не всплывает.

Comment: @Nakilon, попробуйте chrome браузер